# How can I get the number of bytes a C function is compiled to?

Tags: function, gcc

Assuming I am compiling the C source code with gcc, is it possible to know how many bytes each user defined function is compiled to? The resulting ELF binary contains the symbol addresses for function symbols (assuming the binary is not stripped), but is it anyway possible to retrieve the address of the last byte of the function?

The reason I need this information is because I need to write a little static obfuscator/encryptor for ELF binaries. Reversing/disassembling is the sub-optimal solution which I am currently adapting. Finding for function epilogue is not very bulletproof solution indeed. However, gcc can easily spit out this information as part of the compilation process.

Comment: This is not an answer. I have not done this type of thing in years, but from what I remember you have to search the opcode that unwinds the stack, which is where the function ends, then subtract from beginning. I did programmatically not aware of a tool.

Comment: Use function-sections and check their size. The more important question is: why do you want to know it? I smell an XY-problem.

Comment: What do you plan on doing with this information once you get it, assuming it's available somehow?

Comment: Short answer: not really. If you compile just a hello world using GCC + glibc, the mere `#include <stdio.h>` will add a lot of instructions as a result of your compiler/lib choice. Just compare the binaries you get after compiling with gcc + glibc, gcc + -std=c99 (instead of gnu99), and clang + LLVM. You can check the size of the assembly, but the compiled binary is a different thing all together

Comment: What other tools are you planning on using.  For example, if I toss the compiled executable into a dissassembler (say Ida-Pro), I can see the starting address and ending address of each function.  A bit of math will give the size of assembly in bytes.

Comment: @thurizas: Yeah, that's possible, but let's be honest: It gives you an approximation at best. It merely tells you how many bytes of assembly your C function generated when compiled for your specific platform, using your specific toolchain. I don't know what the OP is trying to do, let alone why. I'm with Olaf on this being an X-Y problem

Comment: Updated the original post with required information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All compilers place the information about the size of functions and other tidbits in the symbol table. Use `nm` to inspect this name list. For example, to find the size of the `main` function of the `indent` executable (which must not be stripped), use

```
$ nm -AP indent|grep " main "
indent: main T 0000000000401600 000000000000051d
```

The 'T' indicates a public symbol in the text segment. The `main` function is 0x51d bytes long.

Your [`nm`(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=nm) manual page has all the details. BTW, you can also run `nm` on object files, which usually are not stripped.

Comment: Accurate, makes most sense. Thanks